# ListDensityPlot3D with x-axis in logscale

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Starting from a data set like the one used in this post:

[Importing and visualizing 4D data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195071/importing-and-visualizing-4d-data)

[DATA](https://pastebin.com/WZN5hSTv)

It can be viewed using `ListDensityPlot3D`, as follows:

```
data = Import["~/Desktop/Downloads/WZN5hSTv.txt", "Data"];
ListDensityPlot3D[
  data,
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap",
  OpacityFunction -> (# &),
  PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> Full
]
```

Is there a way to visualize an axis, for example, the x-axis, on a logarithmic scale?